# Find unit vector c

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Find unit vector c such that:

1. Perpendicular with vector a = { 11, 10, 2 }
2. Has $60^{\circ}$ angle with vector b = { 4, 0, 3 }

My solution:

$(a, c) = |a| * |c|*\cos\angle(a,c)=15*cos(90^{\circ})=0$

$(b, c) = |b|*|c|*\cos\angle(b,c)=5*cos(60^{\circ})=\frac{5}{2}$

$(a, c) + (b, c) = (a + b, c)= \frac{5}{2} $

Let $d = a + b = (15, 10, 5) $. Then $ (d, c) = \frac{5}{2} $

$\cos\angle(d,c)=\frac{(d, c)}{|d|*|c|}=\frac{\frac{5}{2}}{\sqrt{350}} = \frac{5}{2\sqrt{350}} $

And I can't find vector c furthermore.

Answer (score 1):

Give names to the components of the unknown vector:
$$
\mathbf{c} = \langle c_1, c_2, c_3 \rangle. 
$$
There are three pieces of information about $\mathbf{c}$, each of which yields an equation involving these components.

(1) Since $\mathbf{c}$ is a unit vector,
$$
c_1^2 + c_2^2 + c_3^2 = 1.
$$

(2) Since $\mathbf{c}$ is perpendicular to $\mathbf{a}$,
$$
\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{c} = 0 
\quad\implies\quad 
11c_1 + 10c_2 + 2c_3 = 0.
$$

(3) Since $\mathbf{c}$ makes angle $60^\circ$ with $\mathbf{b}$,
\begin{align}
\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{c} 
= \lvert \mathbf{a} \rvert \lvert \mathbf{c} \rvert 
\cos(60^\circ)
\quad&\implies\quad 
4c_1 + 0c_2 + 3c_3 = \sqrt{4^2 + 0^2 + 3^2} \, \tfrac12 \\
\quad&\implies\quad 
4c_1 + 3c_3 = \tfrac52 \\
\quad&\implies\quad 
8c_1 + 6c_3 = 5. 
\end{align}

Now, we can solve the nonlinear system of equations
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{aligned} 
c_1^2 + c_2^2 + c_3^2 &= 1 \\
11c_1 + 10c_2 + 2c_3 &= 0 \\
8c_1 + 6c_3 &= 5 
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
by any method.

One possibility: solve each of the linear equations for $c_3$ in terms of the other components, then substitute these expressions into the first equation to obtain a quadratic equation in $c_1$. Each of the two solutions can then be back-substituted into the other equations to find $c_2$ and $c_3$, yielding the two possible vectors $\mathbf{c}$ that you desire. Can you finish from here?